# Mapping @OneToMany on a composite key entity

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have a pretty basic scenario which I fail to map correctly:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Project {
    @Id @Column(name = "p_type")
    private String type;

    @Id @Column(name = "p_name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class ClientProject {
    @Id @Column(name = "client")
    private Long clientId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project")
    private String projectId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_type", referencedColumnName = "project", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private List<Project> projects;
}
```

This causes the following expcetion:

```
referencedColumnNames(project) of com.Project .projects referencing com.ClientProject not mapped to a single property
```

From what I understand, since I am trying to map the `ClientProject` entity to the `Project` entity, hibernate expects two `@JoinComuns`s since `Project` has a composite key.

Since there is no chance for me to change the DB structure, is there an approach that would make this thing work?

Thanks!